# how to find click amount?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print click amount to console, but it must be for all empty areas. Is it possible?

I've tried with button, but couldn't do what I want.

**HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script src="myScript3.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <button onclick="tiklama()">Tıkla!</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**JS:**

```
var x = 0;
function tiklama() {
    console.log(++x);
}
```

Comment: Clicks on empty area ??

Comment: `<body onclick="tiklama()">`?

Comment: @Tushar if you try, you can see that is not working

Comment: Please define "empty areas". White-space between characters? `body` element only? How about possible transparent areas in images? Etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to click event at a higher level, e.g. on `<html>` element and check whether the event's `target` property suites your definition of an "empty area".

```js
var counter = 0;
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click',
    function(e) {
        // counting all clicks except on the interactive elements
        if (!e.target.matches('button,input,textarea,select')) {
            console.log(++counter);
        }
    },
    false);
```

```html
<p>Some text -- considered non-interactive area.</p>
<button>An interactive button</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 0;
function tiklama() {
    alert(++x);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="tiklama()">Tıkla!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could count how many times the page (html) was clicked, like this:

```
var x = 0;
$('html').click(function() {
    ++x;
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = x;
});
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ux0cv8z7/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want click to work on places except the button then add the click event listener to the document object and override it at the button element such as ;

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
document.addEventListener("click", e => tickText.textContent += "tick..! ");
myButton.addEventListener("click", e => e.stopPropagation());
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Tıkla!</button>
<p id="tickText"></p>
```